# Store using Composition API with Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, store, vue-composition-api

TLDR: I wanna use the composition API as a form of caching (no Vuex), such that if I have an input, it's v-model will depend on the variable inside my store, and will change and update accordingly. I also have another part of the html that depends on that variable, but I can't seem to get it to work! Apologies if I was unclear because I'm new at this.

Hi, I would like to do the following. Use the composition API as a store (instead of Vuex), and in my store, I have several variables.

In my app, these variables will be used as v-model in my input. So for example the code will look something like this:

```
//store.ts
const state = reactive({
   input1: ''
   // and so on
})

export default () => state
```

Then in my app.vue (based on the tutorials online)

```
<input v-model="input1" type="text">

<script>
import store from './store'

    setup() {
        const store = store()
        return store
}
```

At this point, I'm stuck. So i understand that my input uses the `input1` from the store, but I want the store to update when my input changes. How do I so? Also, is it possible to add a function such that when I press a button on the html, my variables in my store gets reset to a default value?

Furthermore, let's say I have another piece of code that depends on my input. For example, I wanna show the length of the input, I would need another code in the script, which is something like:

```
computed: {
    calculateStringLength() {
          this.variable = this.input1.length
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work because my input1 is not defined. How do I get this to work?

PS for the ton of questions. I'm really new at this! Thanks in advance!